# Ubuntu 10.10 CD screen doesn't appear, Scrub does

Tags: boot

I have a Ubuntu 10.10 CD that start when inserted in a machine B (Windows)
When I insert it in machine A (Ubuntu 9), it goes to Grub and then start Ubuntu 9

I have a Ubuntu 9 CD. It starts on machine A and does not go to Grub.

I want to install my Ubuntu 10.10 CD on machine A. Is there an easy way to bypass Grub like it seems to do with my Ubuntu 9 CD. Note that I want to re-install the machine from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems in past - I tried to burn it on different CD/DVD and it worked for me. Might be a different case, but worth trying.

Comment: it may indeed has something to do with my CD. I could eventually install Ubuntu 11.10 and the 11.10 CD was detected OK at boot time. Doesn't seem to be a Grub isssue. Not sure what the 10.10 CD problem is though. It works OK on another machine. One thing is the Ubuntu 9 hard disk was not installed originally on this machine but on another Dell laptop.